# Pygame windows isn't responding after a few seconds of running

Tags: python, pygame

I have been working on a Pong game for ***DAYS*** and I know my code is perfect but after a few seconds after running, when I click the start button, it just stops entirely for a few seconds and then gives a small window saying "Python is not responding". I am very annoyed, irritated, and disappointed. My code is over **200** lines long. Here is the code, I am sure there is no mistake in my logic. Try running the code yourself. Here is the code:

```
# Importing libraries
import pygame
import random
import time

# Initializing PyGame
pygame.init()

# Setting a window name
pygame.display.set_caption("Ping Pong")

# Creating a font
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
pong_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 75)

# Set the height and width of the screen
window_width = 700
window_height = 500
size = [window_width, window_height]
game_win = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
game_win2 = pygame.display.set_mode(size)


# Creating a messaging system
def message(sentence, color, x, y, writing_shape, display):
    sentence = writing_shape.render(sentence, True, color)
    display.blit(sentence, [x, y])


# Creating colors
white = (200, 200, 200)
black = (0, 0, 0)
gray = (100, 100, 100)

# Setting up ball
ball_size = 25


class Ball:
    """
    Class to keep track of a ball's location and vector.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0


def make_ball():
    ball = Ball()
    # Starting position of the ball.
    ball.x = 350
    ball.y = 250

    # Speed and direction of rectangle
    ball.change_x = 5
    ball.change_y = 5

    return ball


def main():
    # Scores
    left_score = 0
    right_score = 0

    pygame.init()

    # Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False

    ball_list = []

    ball = make_ball()
    ball_list.append(ball)

    # Right paddle coordinates
    y = 200
    y_change = 0
    x = 50
    # Left paddle coordinates
    y1 = 200
    y1_change = 0
    x1 = 650

    while not done:
        # --- Event Processing
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    y_change = -10

                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    y_change = 10

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -10

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = 10

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                y_change = 0
                y1_change = 0

        y += y_change
        y1 += y1_change

        # Preventing from letting the paddle go off screen
        if y > window_height - 100:
            y -= 10
        if y < 50:
            y += 10
        if y1 > window_height - 100:
            y1 -= 10
        if y1 < 50:
            y1 += 10

        # Logic
        for ball in ball_list:
            # Move the ball's center
            ball.x += ball.change_x
            ball.y += ball.change_y

            # Bounce the ball if needed
            if ball.y > 500 - ball_size or ball.y < ball_size:
                ball.change_y *= -1
            if ball.x > window_width - ball_size:
                ball.change_x *= -1
                left_score += 1
            if ball.x < ball_size:
                ball.change_x *= -1
                right_score += 1

            ball_rect = pygame.Rect(ball.x - ball_size, ball.y - ball_size, ball_size * 2, ball_size * 2)

            left_paddle_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 25, 75)
            if ball.change_x < 0 and ball_rect.colliderect(left_paddle_rect):
                ball.change_x = abs(ball.change_x)

            right_paddle_rect = pygame.Rect(x1, y1, 25, 75)
            if ball.change_x > 0 and ball_rect.colliderect(right_paddle_rect):
                ball.change_x = -abs(ball.change_x)

            if right_score == 10:
                message('RIGHT PLAYER HAS WON!!', white, 300, 200, font, game_win)
                time.sleep(10)
                done = True
            elif left_score == 10:
                message("LEFT PLAYER HAS WON!!", white, 300, 200, font, game_win)
                time.sleep(10)
                done = True

        # Drawing
        # Set the screen background
        game_win.fill(black)

        # Draw the balls
        for ball in ball_list:
            pygame.draw.circle(game_win, white, [ball.x, ball.y], ball_size)

        # Creating Scoreboard
        message("Left player score: " + str(left_score), white, 10, 10, font, game_win)
        message("Right player score: " + str(right_score), white, 490, 10, font, game_win)

        # Drawing a left paddle
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [x, y, 25, 100])
        # Drawing a right paddle
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [x1, y1, 25, 100])


while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    message("Pong", white, 280, 100, pong_font, game_win2)
    if 150 + 100 > mouse[0] > 150 and 350 + 50 > mouse[1] > 350:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, gray, [150, 350, 100, 50])
        if click[0] == 1:
            break
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [150, 350, 100, 50])

    if 450 + 100 > mouse[0] > 450 and 350 + 50 > mouse[1] > 350:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, gray, [450, 350, 100, 50])
        if click[0] == 1:
            pygame.quit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [450, 350, 100, 50])

    message("Start", black, 175, 367, font, game_win2)
    message("Quit", black, 475, 367, font, game_win2)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Wrap-up
    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please help to figure out what is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to update the display at the end of `main` by [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip). Furthermore you have to control the frames per second with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) in the application loop:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    while not done:
        # [...]

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: hmmm ok will try
edit: works fine, thx for the help

Comment: And another issue is when one of the scores hit 10, I have the python is not responding stuff. Can you please help with that?

Comment: @snoopstick In this case your game sleeps for 10 seconds, before it ends  (`time.sleep(10)`)

Comment: what does that mean

Comment: @snoopstick Any call to `time.sleep` makes the game not responding for the specified period of time. Never use `time.sleep` in an pygame application loop

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to fill the window in your while loop.
You should add `game_win.fill(black)` before drawing anything in the second while loop (the one outside main).
Also you should add a `pygame.dispaly.flip()` in your first while loop (the one inside main).

If you don't want your game to create a python error when you close it you should add `pygame.quit()` at the very end in order to properly close the pygame window.

Comment: Actually `game_win.fill(black)` is called, before anything else is drawn.